# rollback operation for Cache to keep synchronization with database in case of any error

Tags: java, database, caching

I want to know the views of experts for my cache synchronization with database.
suppose i have three tables.
(1)Jobs
(2)Jobs_detail
(3)Account

and i have three caches corresponding to above mentioned tables.

i starts operation on Jobs first.then Jobs_detail and then Account.
so first i update (Database Operation) on Jobs and so on..
i mean to say that it is multiple table operations.
if something wrong we can preserve the actual state by calling **connection.rollback**
method on current connection. but what should i do to preserve cache state also , means in synchronization with db.

should i create buffer for holding only current operation and then after successful commit to database this buffer cache will update each corresponding caches ?
or
should i make copy of caches instead ?

Thank You
Mihir Parekh

Answer (score 1):

I would only update the cache state when the database update has been successful.